# Javascript regular expression works sometimes, sometimes not, with the same string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an code to get youtube video id, I using javascript regex to do this but sometimes it works, sometimes not, with the same regex and the same string, why it occurs? What can I do?

If I run this code multiple times, sometimes this return null, sometimes give me an array:

```
var regExp = new RegExp(/^.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|\&v=)([^#\&\?]*).*/);

var url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oAalYg53V30';

console.log(url.match(regExp));

console.log(regExp.exec(url));
```

Comment: @anubhava: this syntax is allowed: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: Next to that, you should not re-use a `RegExp` object, because it has memory.

Comment: @Stephan only with the `g` flag, which in not the case here.

Comment: Something else is at play here.  Here's your code (as posted above) in jsfiddle, and after 100,000 iterations there is still only 1 result... http://jsfiddle.net/vt48xqhL/

Comment: Why are you passing a literal regexp to a regexp constructor? Also, you do not need to escape `&` ever, nor `?` when it is in a character set. Finally, anchoring the regexp to the beginning of the string with `^` and then immediately following it with `.*` is the same as not anchoring it all.

Comment: @torazaburo; you can use this syntax since ECMAScript 6.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Which syntax?

Comment: @torazaburo: This one: `new RegExp(/..../)`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte How is it different from just saying `/.../`? It has always been possible to say `new Regxp(/.../)`. The change introduced by ES6 was that you can change the flags with this format, by saying `new Regexp(/.../, 'i')`.

Comment: @torazaburo: nothing except that you can pass the flags in the second parameter.